# Uber API returns 404 'Invalid product'

Tags: node.js, uber-api

I have a valid token and make a request to GET /products. I take a `product_id` from the response and send it to POST /requests along with

Body:

```
{
    "product_id":"my-valid-product-id",
    "start_longitude":38.9,
    "start_latitude":-77.0,
    "end_longitude":"-77.0",
    "end_latitude":"38.9"
}
```

The response is :

```
{"message":"Invalid product \"my-valid-product-id\". Available: ","code":"not_found"}
```

Any idea what's up?

*edit* This issue has been resolved. The wrong GPS coordinates were being sent so Uber rejected the ride request. The "Available :" string means no Ubers were available at the incorrect GPS location I used.

Comment: Have you tried a different product? Your request seems to match whats in the documentation.  I don't see any issues with the API call.  The documentation specifies that a 404 status is returned when "An invalid product ID was requested. Retry the API call with a valid product ID."

Comment: Also are you using the URL: https://sandbox-api.uber.com/v1/requests ?

Comment: I have tried with both the sandbox and production URLs. Same error. I have also tried a variety of product ids.

Comment: For example, I am using `dee8691c-8b48-4637-b048-300eee72d58d` which is a uberX in Indianapolis, and `9ffa937e-7d2e-4bcf-bc2b-ffec4ef24380` which is an UberXL in Washington DC

Comment: The `requests/estimate` also returns 404 in the same fashion.

Comment: Ok.... twas my own mistake combined with some incorrect documentation. Spot the bug?    ```{start_longitude: params.latitude,
   start_latitude: params.longitude}```